# Rails 3.2.2 not executing rjs

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, rjs

I'm following the book *Pragmatic Agile Web Development With Rails 4th Edition*, BUT I'm using Rails 3.2.2 instead of 3.0.5 as recommended in the book:

```
~$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16) [i686-linux]
~$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.2
```

I got stuck when including AJAX to redraw the Cart without reloading the page. Here is the create action in line_items_controller.rb:

```
def create
    @cart = current_cart
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to(store_url) }
        format.js 
        format.json { render json: @line_item, status: :created, location: @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

And here is my RJS file create.js.rjs (under app/views/line_items):

```
page.alert('NO PROBLEM HERE')
page.replace_html('cart', render(@cart))
```

However, when I click the button that starts this action:

```
<%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_items_path(:product_id => product), :remote => true %>
```

I get the following error in the development log:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template line_items/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/me/src_rails/depot/app/views"
):
  app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:47:in `create'
```

If I change the filename of create.js.rjs to create.js.erb, the problem is corrected:

```
Rendered line_items/create.js.erb (0.4ms)
```

but nothing happens in the view.... not even the alert. 
What am I missing? 
What is the difference between file.js.erb and file.js.rjs?

Comment: hey guy! I found your post on google. I faced the same situation. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It looks like `rjs` has been [removed as the default](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/4/21/jquery-new-default/) as of Rails 3.1. You could get it back by installing the `prototype-rails` gem, but I think you should just use jQuery, which is the new default.

As for your code, the reason it's not working is that it's an `rjs` template being interpreted as `.js.erb`, and this is likely just producing invalid JavaScript (you should see errors in the JavaScript console in your browser). An `rjs` template used to set the `page` variable for you, and you would write Ruby code using it to manipulate your page. In a `.js.erb` template, it works more like in your `.html.erb` views. You write actual JavaScript, with Ruby embedded using `<% %>` tags. So the code in `create.js.erb` should look something like this:

```js
 alert('NO PROBLEM HERE');
 $('#cart').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(@cart)) %>");
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm surely switching to jquery then.

Answer (score 6):

In rails >= 3.1 there is no jquery-rjs anymore. But you can use CoffeeScript here:
`line_items/create.js.coffee`:

```
alert 'NO PROBLEM HERE'
$('#cart').html '<%= j render(@cart) %>'
```

or something like that.