# The AJAX request cannot see the effect without refresh the browser in Rails

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I faced the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10148134/rails-3-2-2-not-executing-rjs) with this guy

I change rjs to js.erb just like him. And we all use `<%= button_to 'Add to Cart',line_items_path(:product_id => product) ,:remote=>true %>` to send an AJAX request to the controller. `format.js` to fine and execute create.js.erb. But the cart did not add anything.

log result :

`Rendered line_items/_line_item.html.erb (4.3ms)
  Rendered carts/_cart.html.erb (8.0ms)
  Rendered line_items/create.js.erb (8.8ms)`

That's the index.html.erb we send the AJAX request

```
<% if notice %>
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<% end %>
<h1>Your Pragmatic Catalog</h1>

<% @products.each do |product| %>
<div class="entry">
<%= link_to image_tag(product.image_url), line_items_path(:product_id => product), html_options = {:method => :post} %>
    <h3><%= product.title %></h3>
    <%=sanitize product.description %>
    <div class="price_line">
      <span class="price"><%= number_to_currency(product.price,:precision=>3) %></span>
      <%= button_to 'Add to Cart',line_items_path(:product_id => product) ,:remote=>true %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

That's the line_items controller function to handle the request

```
  # POST /line_items
  # POST /line_items.json
  def create
     # for exercise only
    session[:counter] = nil

    @cart = current_cart
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)



    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to store_index_path }
        format.js
        format.json { render json: @line_item, status: :created, location: @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end


  end
```

create.js.erb

```
$('#cart').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(@cart)) %>");
```

Comment: You'll need to add more information. There's not enough information for us to help you.

Comment: Do you have a `create.js.erb` file in your views folder? Rails needs to know what to serve back to you when you're requesting a .js (AJAX) response.

Comment: I have a `create.js.erb` in inside it. The problem seems to be that there is no AJAX request sent from the `index.html.erb` to the controller so the `format`  always is `format.html`

Comment: I figure out what going on now :)
The book teached me to change the javascript tag into :default but not 'application'

Comment: but it causes me double render problem now :(

Comment: What's a "double render problem"?

Comment: I fixed it . But the cart cannot added anything without refresh :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed the problem.
Thanks to the [great article](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-js-erb-remote-response-not-executing/comment-page-1/#comment-4374) which tell me the ability of firebug to see the source of response from AJAX request.
And [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com) helps me checkout the javascript syntax.
And finally I would like to thanks the Firebug which is such a great tool.

**The problem is that the javascript is not being executed if there is any syntax error.**

**In my problem:**

I should use single-quoted instead of double-qouted to wrap the render results. The render results comes out with many HTML with "", and "" which wrap them will cause syntax error in javascript. (double-qouted in double-qouated is not allowed)

So I simply change `$('#cart').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(@cart)) %>");` to
`$('#cart').html('<%= escape_javascript(render(@cart))%>');`

**I hope this answer will help the others who also suffer from this nightmare staff.
Help me increase the question rate if this is possible :)**

Answer (score 1):

Let's use j() helper method: $('#cart').html("<%=j render(@cart) %>");