# How to render a partial from an assets Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to render a partial from a javascript in my assets directory. I found that I can't call the render method within the assets directory. But I cant move my ajax command out of the assets directory either. So my Question is now, how to pass my ajax result onto the action.js file in my view.

So I call the ajax on a onclick jQuery event:

/app/javascript/mymodel.js.coffee

```
$(document).ready ->
---some actions ----
$('.myid').click ->
    ---some action---
    $.ajax 'mypath'
        dataType: 'json'
        success: (result)->
            ---render result in partial on myid-div---
```

So how do I pass my beloved result and myid onto:

/app/views/mymodel/show.js.erb

```
$('.myid').html("<%= escape_javascript( render( :partial => 'myartial') ) %>");
```

To render it out?

I'm banging my head around this for quite some time, so I would really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready ->
---some actions ----
$('.myid').click ->
    ---some action---
    $.ajax 'mypath'
        dataType: 'json'
        params: (pass in what you need, i don't know the exact syntax, just google it)
        success: (result)->
            ---render result in partial on myid-div---
controller

def show
  @result = params[:result]
end

view
show.js.erb
$('#some_id').html('<%= render("mypartial").html_safe %>');
```

@result is accessible now

Pass your result as a parameter from your AJAX call to your controller method.  Then instantiate an instance variable (@result for example from the parameter), that way your views is not able to use the instance variable.

Comment: Cool I like that answer. Sadly I'm not able to create my code out of it. My ajax call does GET me my information. But how do I call the render in the success function? Can u walk me through it? Whats the function call to say render _mypartial as format = js with this argument?

Comment: so after the show method runs it will execute a JS file (it will look for show.js.erb). (check updated answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can call the mymodel controller's method to render your partial, but the file name of partial should start with an underscore `_`

In your example, these code  `render :partial => 'show'` may work for your to render js if you put them into mymodel controller and you should rename `show.js.erb` to `_show.js.erb` in the view of mymodel.

To be optimistic, you should be able to render the `_show.js.erb` and you can see somethings like `render _show.js.erb` successful inside your terminal.

But It doesn't means that the rails was processing the js.erb as javascript, because there are syntax error in your js.erb ( I am absolutely sure!! ). 
So you may also change

`$('.myid').html("<%= escape_javascript( render( :partial => 'myartial') ) %>");`

to

`$('.myid').html('<%= escape_javascript( render( :partial => 'myartial') ) %>');`

Check out [my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220816/the-ajax-request-cannot-see-the-effect-without-refresh-the-browser-in-rails) for more details. I faced the similar problem before.
It will also show you an example of how to send a ajax call and render .js.erb.

`:remote => true` will send a ajax request to `line_items_path`.

And according to the routing, it will call the create method, format.js will render `create.js.erb` by convention. Alternatively, I can render the js.erb with `format.js {render :partial=> "create"}` if `_create.js.erb` exist

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thinks thats not part of my Problem. The 'show' was not my partial it was my js template for the action. my show has an _ in front of it. And its not called so far, because I dont know how. Why do u think I should replace the " with the ' in my show.js?

Comment: rendering partial is common for ajax call. [check this out](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render). The reason I think you should replace "" with ' because I predict the partials of myartial will come out many ", and you cannot enclose  "" inside "". 
You can use Firebug to see the ajax response

Comment: I have refined my answer:) check it out to help you understand how to render js