# Button doesn't update in Ajax - Rails Tutorial

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org

I know, the current already asked, but I can not fix it...

**Gemfile**

```
 gem 'rails', '3.2.9'
 gem 'jquery-rails' , '2.0.2'
```

**class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController**

```
  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])
    current_user.follow!(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end
```

**create.js.erb**

```
  $("#follow_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('shared/unfollow')) %>")
```

I have partial **\app\views\shared\_unfollow.html.erb**

```
 <%= form_for current_user.relationships.find_by_followed_id(@account), 
        :html => { :method => :delete }, :remote => true do |f|%>
     <div class="actions"><%= f.submit 'unfollow' %></div>
 <% end %>
```

if press the button, the state does not change. Try add ".html_safe" doesn't work too.

But if I do

```
$("#follow_form").html("bla bla bla")
```

or

```
$("#follow_form").html("<%= 10+10 %>")
```

it's work

Comment: And if i press button and update page manualy, state сhanges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change

```
$("#follow_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('shared/unfollow')) %>")
```

**to**

```
$("#follow_form").html('<%= escape_javascript(render("shared/unfollow")) %>');
```

Errors may be caused by invalid syntax of the javascript, so your javascript will not be executed. You will not see the erorrs in any browsers. But you can used Firefox to see the Ajax response.

I faced the  [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220816/the-ajax-request-cannot-see-the-effect-without-refresh-the-browser-in-rails)  before

Comment: try change " to ' , no ganges. But firefox console write "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error", it is something :)

Comment: I have added `;` behind just now ,haha. See the log file, does the application execute that JS file?

Comment: Also Download the firebug and check the ajax response comeback

Comment: greate! The button changes state. Apparently, where it lost in the variables. Appointed afresh and earned. but sent two requests, well, that I'll deal. Thanks

Comment: it lost in the variables??

Comment: 'ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class):
    1: <%= form_for current_user.relationships.find_by_followed_id(@account), :html => { :method => :delete }, :remote => true do |f|%>
    2:     <div class="actions"><%= f.submit t(:button_unfollow) %></div>
    3: <% end %>
  app/views/shared/_unfollow.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_shared__unfollow_html_erb__850533283_35511012'
  app/views/relationships/create.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_relationships_create_js_erb___239460557_35579604'
  app/controllers/relationships_controller.rb:7:in `create''