# render update and replace_html not working in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Currently  i am upgrading my app to rails 4 and using RJS in many places.
later on i cames to know that RJS removed and its still available through prototype-rails gem .so that I have added the gem and included in applicaton.js,but still I am getting the same issue.

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template lease/update, application/update with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html, :xml, :html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :rjs]}
```

sample code:
we are using the old extension:
ex:

```
def ajax_refer
 render :update do |page|
            page.replace_html  "lease_container", :partial => "/lease/property_pipeline", :locals => {:note_collection => @note, :portfolio_collection => @portfolio_collection}
end
end
my view is property_pipeline.html.erb
my application.js have

//= require prototype
//= require prototype_ujs
//= require effects
//= require dragdrop
//= require controls
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_self
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: your files need to have the right extension like `.js` for rails to find them. you could also add a mime alias to map the extension.

Comment: please look at the updated question

Answer (score 1):

`:rjs` is included among `:handlers` and that's good, but it's hard to know what else is missing from the snippet. Per [prototype-rails](https://github.com/rails/prototype-rails), did you also remember to update development configs? `config.action_view.debug_rjs = true` in `config/environments/development.rb`?

There's a related [Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10148134/rails-3-2-2-not-executing-rjs) about rjs being [removed as the default JS library as of Rails 3.1](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/4/21/jquery-new-default/) and how to handle JS rendering.

According to that thread:

> As for your code, the reason it's not working is that it's an rjs
>   template being interpreted as .js.erb, and this is likely just
>   producing invalid JavaScript.

It might be easier to simply try changing the `update.js.rjs` to `update.js` in your `views/lease` folder and use jQuery along the lines of:

`$('#lease_container').html("<%= escape_javascript render property_pipeline %>");`

Please let me know if this turns out useful. It would have been helpful to include what actually was rendered following the missing template call ... it would indicate the interpreted extension.